# How to change each item of Treeview in Devextreame side-navigation-menu to a link tag (<a><a/>) to have "Open link in new" tab option?

Tags: reactjs, devextreme

I'm using **Devextreame** by **React** in a project which has its built-in side-navigation-menu. The menu is a `Treeview` component gives its sub-menus as an array by the `items` property.

```
<TreeView
          ref={treeViewRef}
          items={items}
          keyExpr={'path'}
          selectionMode={'single'}
          focusStateEnabled={false}
          expandEvent={'click'}
          onItemClick={selectedItemChanged}
          onContentReady={onMenuReady}
          width={'100%'}
          expandedExpr="false"
/>
```

So there is no accebility to the tags of items to change them to a `<a>` tag to have "Open link in new" option as a link.

Does any body know how to change each item of Treeview in Devextreame side-navigation-menu to a link tag `<a>` to have "Open link in new" tab option?